# Using iText to create PDF

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to create a PDF using iText and I'm having a great deal of difficulty.  In short, what I want to do is:

- Read in a template pdf
- Make a copy in memory of the template
- Draw a table on the copy
- Write the copy pdf to an outputstream

So far, it's looking like this

```
// read in template pdf
InputStream templateStream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(labelsTemplate);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateStream);

// create a table in a new document
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, os);
document.open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("row 1; cell 1"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("row 1; cell 2"));
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```

Can someone explain how I can make a copy of the template once I've used PdfReader to read it?  Is there a way to write the table onto the template copy and not a new document?

For future references, here's what I've done:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"scheduler-labels.pdf\"");
ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

// read in template pdf
InputStream templateStream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(labelsTemplate);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateStream);

// make new pdf document to draw table and output to memory
Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSize(1));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

// write table
document.open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setWidthPercentage(110);
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("row 1; cell 1"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("row 1; cell 2"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("row 2; cell 1"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("row 2; cell 2"));
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
document.close();

// read in newly generated table pdf
PdfReader tableReader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
ByteArrayOutputStream baosCombined = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(tableReader, baosCombined);

// get a page from the template pdf
PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(reader, 1);

// add to background of table pdf
PdfContentByte background;
background = stamper.getUnderContent(1);
background.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

stamper.close();
tableReader.close();
reader.close();

// write to servlet output
baosCombined.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Comment: Can you use some other api ? If yes, have  you tried jasper ?

Comment: Have you studied the iText sample [Stationery.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=114) yet?

Comment: NullPointerException I have to use iText for this project.

Comment: mkl Thank you!  That example is just what I needed.  Now I am having other issues with positioning the table.  But I have it working like the example.

Comment: It seems as your problem was solved. It would help if you answer the question and accept your own answer. Otherwise it always catches my eye as an unanswered question.

Comment: Accepted mkl's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As studying the sample referenced in my comment was *just what [Tuan] needed,* I formulate it as an answer:

The sample [Stationery.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=114) from [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) essentially shows how to use the contents of a given PDF as background (stationery-like) of a new PDF while filling its foreground with new content.

The central code is as follows:

```
public class Stationery extends PdfPageEventHelper
{
    [...]

    public void createPdf(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 72, 36);
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        useStationary(writer);
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        [... add content to PDF ...]
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }

    [...]

    public void useStationary(PdfWriter writer) throws IOException
    {
        writer.setPageEvent(this);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(STATIONERY);
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    }

    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        writer.getDirectContentUnder().addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }

    [...]
}
```

As implicit `close()` calls have been removed more and more recently, the `PdfReader reader` instantiated in `useStationary` nowerdays should be stored in some variable of `Stationery` and closed after `createPdf` has executed.